# Using a standard profile name in an AWS Credentials Provider?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

How do I specify a named profile (e.g. "myprofile") as an AWS credentials provider?

I have an AWS Kinesis client which currently uses credentials stored in the app bundle:

```
KinesisProducerConfiguration config = new KinesisProducerConfiguration();
config.setCredentialsProvider(new PropertiesFileCredentialsProvider("credentials.properties"));
```

and would like to modify it such that it can use a profile specified in the standard AWS config file `~/.aws/credentials`.

I can get the credentials like this:

```
    String awskey = new ProfilesConfigFile()
                            .getAllProfiles()
                            .get("myprofile")
                            .getCredentials()
                            .getAWSAccessKeyId();
```

What do I need to do in the first snippet of code such that I can specify a profile in the credentials file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it looks like [`ProfileCredentialsProvider`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/profile/ProfileCredentialsProvider.html) might do what you want, *e.g.*:

```
config.setCredentialsProvider(new ProfileCredentialsProvider("credentials.properties", "myprofile"));
```

Hope this helps!